# Export each lines of csv in a seperated txt file display key error

Tags: python, csv, format, reader

So I am trying to export each line of a particular column in my csv file in a txt file; I have more than 100 lines.

```
import csv


import csv

with open('MF.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        file_name = "{}_{}.txt".format(row['id'], row['labels'])
        line = row['sentences']
        with open(file_name, 'w') as output:
            output.write(line)
```

error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv_to_txt.py", line 7, in <module>
    file_name = "{}_{}.txt".format(row['id']; row['labels'])
KeyError: 'id'
```

I am having difficulties to figure out why it throws  KeyError.

file looks like this

```
id;labels;sentences
1;M;On a presque laissé 
2;M;ça ne changera rien
3;M; [...], je voyais ça la lune.
4;M;ça existe 
5;M;Ce qui.
6;M;La facilité de changer.
```

[image]

Comment: please specify the _correct_ delimiter when creating your `DictReader`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `;` as a delimiter in your csv, you need to specify that when you create an instance of [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
```